# ASP.NET MVC - calling Razor @helper from another @helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

I've been implementing some `@helper` functions in Razor based on [Scott Gu's post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx), and things are going pretty well.

What I was wondering though, is if it's possible to call one `@helper` from another.  For example, I have the following helper that displays date and time for a `DateTime?`:

```
@helper DateTimeDisplay(DateTime? date)
{
    if (date.HasValue)
    {
        @date.Value.ToShortDateString()<br />
        <text>at</text> @date.Value.ToShortTimeString()
    }
    else
    {
        <text>-</text>
    }
}
```

This works fine, but in some situations I have other fields that are not nullable, so I tried adding this to keep things DRY:

```
@helper DateTimeDisplay(DateTime date)
{
    DateTimeDisplay(new DateTime?(date));
}
```

This compiles and runs OK, but when it renders it just shows as an empty string for the non-nullable `DateTime`.  Here's the markup that calls the `@helper` functions. `Model.UpdateDate` is a regular `DateTime` and `Model.LastRun` is a `DateTime?`

```
...
<tr>
    <td>Last&nbsp;updated&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="value-field">@Helpers.DateTimeDisplay(Model.UpdateDate)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Last&nbsp;run&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="value-field">@Helpers.DateTimeDisplay(Model.LastRun)</td>
</tr>
...
```

Is there a way to render one `@helper` function by calling it from another?

Comment: dont get your point completely...can you rephrase your question plz

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to write `@DateTimeDisplay(...)` to print the return value to the page.